# External Data Source

Tags: apex, visualforce, odata

I am trying to set up an External data Sourcein my developer Org. However I do not get any option other than "Simple URL" in the Type drop down.

How can we get the other values to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External Data source type are available in following way

**Simple URL External Data Source**

Available in: both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience

Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

**Lightning Connect—OData 2.0 or 4.0 Adapter,Lightning Connect—Salesforce Adapter, Custom Adapter**

Available in: Salesforce Classic

Available in: Developer Edition

Available for an extra cost in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a Lightning Connect license.  It is available for free on Developer Edition but requires an extra fee for all other orgs.